# Array values from textboxes

Tags: c#

I have a 16 element int array and 16 textboxes (textBox1, textBox2 ....) that look like 4x4 matrix. Is there any way to put textboxes values to every array element not using code like this:

```
array[1] = (int)textBox1.Text;
array[2] = (int)textBox2.Text;
```

Comment: Nothing cleaner than that. You could use `(this.FindControl("textBox" + i) as TextBox).Text` but then you lose type safety

Comment: Agreeing with that above. Another possibility would be to set up an array of `TextBox` controls, like `Control[] aTextBoxes = new Control[] { textBox1, textBox2, ..};`, then looping through them with a `for(int i=0; i < aTextBoxes.Length; i++) array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(aTextBoxes[i].Text);` (complitly ommiting `try-catch` blocks or checking the length of the array first)

Comment: You better go with a proper naming of your controls or define an ``TextBox[]`` field in the form class. Also, there are things like [jagged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2s05feca.aspx) and [rectangular/multidimensional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s7e8s029(v=VS.80).aspx) arrays.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to store the references to the `TextBox` instances in an array.

```
TextBox[] Boxes;
```

And then use a 'for' loop to populate the values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
   array[i] = (int)Boxes[i].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function to get the text box's text as an integer using it's "index" from the form's control collection:

```
int GetBoxText(int index)
{
  return Convert.ToInt32(this.Controls["textBox" + i.ToString()].Text);
}
```

Note that this has no error checking of any kind. You could add some if you wanted to. All this does is get the text of the control named textBox + whatever i is from the form's control collection and convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best way to design is by the way it's meant to be. In particular, [rectangular/multidimensional arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s7e8s029(v=VS.80).aspx) may be useful in this scenario:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    TextBox[,] textBoxes;
    int[,] values;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBoxes = new TextBox[4, 4];
        values = new int[textBoxes.GetLength(0), textBoxes.GetLength(1)];
        for(int r = 0; r < textBoxes.GetLength(0); r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < textBoxes.GetLength(1); c++) {
                values[r, c] = int.Parse(textBoxes[r, c].Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```